# Is there a reason my camera rotation is not correct?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I've been working on a Portal-esque game using **Unity 3D 2019.3.0a8**. I have had a good bit of experience using this engine, but I've come across a bug that has baffled me.

In my scene I have two 'Portals', each with a camera connected to a render texture, which is the material of the opposite portal mesh. I have written a short script which moves the portal cameras along with the player's camera, to keep the perspective of the render texture looking realistic, but I realised the cameras were facing the same way as the player camera (on the y axis). In my code (which I've attached) I have tried to flip the y-rotation of the cameras by setting the y-rotation to:

```
yrotation - 180
```

but it seems it does nothing. The reason this confuses me so much is because I have made so many games relying on rotation, and I've never come across a bug like this. I apologise If I have been slightly unclear, as I'm not too sure how to describe it, so I'll attach the Unity project for you to look at.

Thank you in advance.

*The project file is at http://biotechgames.net/dir/portal_help.zip .*

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the y rotation by -1 should flip the y rotation of the camera(s). You should try using this code `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y * -1f, transform.rotation.z);` This will flip the rotation of the y-axis. If this doesn't work, Brackeys on Youtube has made a great tutorial on how to make portals (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuQao3hEKfs) and you should watch it. See what you are doing wrong. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, It was actually Brackeys who inspired me! The issue still occurs with your code, which is confusing. It seems the portal camera's rotation does not change along with the players one, hopefully http://biotechgames.net/dir/portal%20issue.jpg helps.with visualisation